# Xamarin.Forms Editor Placeholder Text Not Wrapping

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

My XAML Editor in my Xamarin.forms app is not wrapping the placeholder when it is too long to fit in the StackLayout.  However, I really wanted to use the Editor for the reason that it can do multi-line input and text.  Please let me know how I can achieve this.  Below is my XAML code.

```
<ScrollView>
<StackLayout>
<Frame BorderColor="LightGray" HasShadow="False" Padding="0">
<Editor x:Name="Editor" MaxLength="450" HeightRequest="200" Placeholder="Long placeholder text, the text should wrap but it doesn't.  It just keeps going on and not being visible on the screen"></Editor>
</Frame>
</StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Below is an image of my result when I try to make the placeholder text be: "This is very very long placeholder text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet hi hi hi hi"

[image]

Comment: I tested your line of code and it is wrapping, we probably need more context

Comment: Hmmm I added that it is in a scrollview and stacklayout now.  Could the scrollview be the reason?

Comment: No. I test with the scrollview, it is wrapping. Check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/GPBkMhq

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the system designing of iOS .If you do want to let the placeHolder warp in iOS , you could use **Custom Renderer** (add a label to display the placeholder)

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using App11.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Editor),typeof(MyEditorRenderer))]
namespace App11.iOS
{
    public class MyEditorRenderer: EditorRenderer
    {

        UILabel placeHolderLabel;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                if(placeHolderLabel==null)
                {
                    var frame = this.Bounds;

                    placeHolderLabel = new UILabel() {Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(5,-10,380,Element.HeightRequest/2) };
                    placeHolderLabel.Lines = 0;
                    placeHolderLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
                   // placeHolderLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
                    placeHolderLabel.TextColor = UIColor.LightGray;
                    UpdateplaceHolder();
                    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this,new ObjCRuntime.Selector("UpdateplaceHolder"),UITextView.TextDidChangeNotification,null);

                }
            }

        }

        [Export("UpdateplaceHolder")]
        void UpdateplaceHolder()
        {
            if (Control.Text.Length>0)
            {

                this.placeHolderLabel.RemoveFromSuperview();

                return;
            }
            this.placeHolderLabel.Font = this.TextView.Font;
            this.placeHolderLabel.TextAlignment = this.TextView.TextAlignment;
            this.placeHolderLabel.Text = Element.Placeholder;
            Element.Placeholder = "";
           // this.placeHolderLabel.SizeToFit();
            this.AddSubview(placeHolderLabel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this solution.  It worked a little bit, but the words still get cut off. For example, when I try putting "Hi this is really long placeholder text.  I am trying doing a custom renderer for iOS.  How does that look when the program is running?", what shows up is "Hi this is really long placeholder text. I am (wrap, m is cut off a little)  doing a custom renderer with iOS. How _do_ (wrap) look when the program is running?

Comment: It only worked in bigger screens when I tried testing it on different simulators

Comment: You need to set the frame of ` placeHolderLabel = new UILabel() {Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(5,-10,380,Element.HeightRequest/2) };`as you need in your case , my code is just for demo .

Comment: This doesn't work if you have to hardcode the Frame width

Answer (score 0):

The full solution to this involves two things

1. Using an AutoLayout constraint for the width of the placeholder (UILabel), see this [XF Github Issue for the code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12062)
2. Once you have the label wrapping you need to make sure that the Editor container is big enough to allow the UILabel to be seen. You could use a HeightRequest attribute on the Editor but that locks the height. Locking the height causes scrolling within the control when the text is too long, this is a problem when the Editor is already in a ScrollView. The answer is to override SizeThatFits in the CustomRenderer ([rickclephas](https://github.com/rickclephas)) to the rescue again with [this post](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5659#issuecomment-689464722)